# Exchange Web Service C# Issue,

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I have a couple of applications that use the EWS in c#. Some of them may run at the same time. When it does overlap, I usually see this error:

The process cannot access the file 'C:\Windows\system32\EwsResponse.txt' because it is being used by another process.

Is there any way I can avoid this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable tracing:

```
service.TraceEnabled = false;
```

Then the EWS client components will stop writing EwsRequest.txt and EwsResponse.txt files.

Comment: Thank you @dlatikay, that did it.